# Segmentation fault using DS18B20 Temperature Sensor

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a code in C++ that takes the reading from **raspberry pi3** using **DS18B20** . The code is compiled without errors but when i try to run it . It gives an error of **segmentation fault** .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <iostream>

#define  BUFSIZE  128
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
float temp;
    int i, j;
        size_t ret;
    FILE *fd;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char tempBuf[5];
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
    while(1){   
        fd = fopen("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000085c3551/w1_slave", O_RDONLY);
        if(fd != NULL){
            perror("open device file error");
            break;
        }
        while(1){
            ret = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, fd);
            if(0 == ret){
                break;  
            }
            if(-1 == ret){
                if(errno == EINTR){
                    continue;   
                }
                std::cout<<"Read Error";                
                fclose(fd);
                break;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<sizeof(buf);i++){
            if(buf[i] == 't'){
                for(j=0;j<sizeof(tempBuf);j++){
                    tempBuf[j] = buf[i+2+j];    
                }
            }   
        }

        temp = (float)atoi(tempBuf) / 1000;


        std::cout<< "%.3f C\n" << temp;
        fclose(fd);

        //delay(500);
        }
}
`
```

In compiling no errors occcurs . 
it(stackoverflow site) kept on asking to to add more details i have no more details to add this is the only problem i am facing and the above code is compiling but not running .Hopefully some of you can help

Comment: Don't you have JTAG debugging tools? I haven't work with the Raspberry but can't imagine it much different than other microprocessors.

Comment: In `tempBuf[j] = buf[i+2+j];`, `i+2+j` can theoretically be `BUFSIZE + 5`, which is a very bad index.

Comment: You're also reading into `buffer`, but copying from `buf`, which is uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

- The second argument to the `fopen()` call must be a string, in your case it should be `"r"` to open the file in read-only mode
- `fopen()` returns NULL if the file couldn't be opened, and a non-NULL pointer otherwise; your code that checks if `(fd != NULL)` should check if `(fd == NULL)` instead
- As pointed out in a comment to your question, the expression `buf[i+2+j]` could access a location outside the `buf` array
- `tempBuf` isn't guaranteed to have a string terminator character in it, so when you call `atoi(tempBuf)` this function could access past the end of the `tempBuf` array